# how to find out if a content (from specific web site) successfully shared on social network using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, social-networking

it's been a while we're having a very very big issue. We have developed a web site that has a scoring system by which users can increase their scores and get promoted.

one part of the scoring system is that the users can share the web sites' content on social networks and receive a specific score but the big issue is that how are we supposed to find out that if the content is successfully shard by user (not only clicking on share button and canceling the operation later) by asp.net
on the other hand how can I figure this out **using asp.net server side codes**(preferably not using javascript)????

I've tried some codes for instance for facebook sharing from several sites such as developer.facebook.com,sharethis.com etc but most of them only include the following standard script library (written by facebook) which I don't know how to find out the success of sharing operation by user from it

```
(function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

I also found a sample which used server side codes and seemed to be what I'd been looking for but an other big issue is that the codes run with personal ApplicationID and I can't get ApplicationID from facebook because when I enter developers.facebook.com/apps I'm gently asked to "Register as a Developer" in order to proceed and when I click on the button another popup comes up asking me me to give a cell phone number for verification so I typed my cell phone number but nothing sent by facebook and consequently I couldn't get AppID.

please help me it's been really a big trouble.

thanks a million.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik you can´t find out server side, you can try debugging the response of the [Share Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog) of the JavaScript SDK.

But the most important thing to know is that what you are trying to do is not allowed according to the [platform policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/):

> Only incentivize a person to log into your app, enter a promotion on
>   your app’s Page, or check-in at a place. Don’t incentivize other
>   actions.

That means, you are not allowed to reward users for sharing or liking. People always need to share/like/comment if they really want to, not because they get something for it.